# How Do I get past the Magnemite screen on Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Shortly after I start a pokemon go account, a screen appears that has a picture of magnemite on it with a box at the bottom you can type in. What am I supposed to type in the box? How do I get past this screen? I've tried typing in magnemite, but nothing's working. How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a glitch which should have hopefully been fixed by now

Comment: Woah people really hated this question. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your game, but as the other person said, it's probably a website restriction thing or a glitch. If you are on a phone, than just try to reinstall.

Answer (score -4):

It's an "I'm not a robot" test where you have to click on street signs to verify that you are not a robot... The reason its not working is because if you have website restrictions on, it will restrict the robot test...